# Problem with looping over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, vectorization

I have a dataframe (`df`) of 100 (will be more eventually) rows and 2689 columns. I have to apply a function say `fn1(df,a,b)` on each row. The `fn1` itself has a for loop, which I cannot avoid. So, I want to speed up applying `fn1` to all rows of `df`. The `a` and `b` arguments of `fn1` are some other arguments I need to compute some value inside `fn1`. I saw a lot about not to use **itertools, using `apply()` and best-being vectorization. ** However, I cannot see any time difference when I use these.** I use them as below. Can anyone please correct the commands so that time speedup happens? I provide a smaller case of df of size 5*2413 here.

**My first naive approach:**

```
for i in df.values:
#performing the operation
```

**Second approach:**

```
df['f']= df.apply(lambda row: fn1(row,a,b), axis=1, raw=True)
#taking time 1.2 for df of size 5*2689
```

**Third approach:**

```
df['f']=fn1(df.values,a,b)
#same time
```

**Fourth approach:**

```
    vectfunc=np.vectorize(fn1)       
    df['f'] = vectfunc(df[df.columns[0:]],a, b)  
    #or
   df['f'] = vectfunc(df,a, b)
```

In this fourth approach, both give me an error 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable because inside fn1 I do an operation list(whatever I get as the row in the 1st argument) before proceeding to perform my fn1 operations. Whereas df[df.columns[0:]] or df is making the 1st argument only to have 1 element i.e. 1st element of row 1 instead of entire row.

**Can anyone please suggest how to speed up in this case?** If you think the data size is small to conclude, then please atleast correct my fourth approach so that i can apply vectorization correctly.

Update: I see np.vectorize doesn't speed up per se. In that case, what about pandas vectorization? Can I apply it here? if so, how may I do it. Please see my comment below.

**Note: Anyone reading the accepted answer may also read my final comment that says how I ended up speeding up the code.**

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not meant to speed up code. It is only meant to be used for convenience. I find the name miss-leading since it does not really vectorize anything (based on the definition of "vectorization" provided by the Numpy doc itself). `df.apply` do not vectorize anything either. Pandas loops are known to be very slow. The only solution is generally to manually modify `fn1` so it can operate on array (ie. truly vectorize it). There is no magical way to automatically vectorize a scalar function operating on Pandas dataframes.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I understand. Inside my fn1(i,a,b), I usually do list(i) before I proceed to use the values of the list to do some operation. So, in this case, am I not already defining my fn1 operation to perform on just 1 row as you said? This is where I am confused. My fn1 is designed to operate on a given row whereas I do not want to call it from a loop iterating over rows. Any suggestion you can give here? What about pandas vectorize? Can I use it here?

Comment: My point is that you cannot vectorize a black-box function `fn1`. It needs to be modified to be fast/vectorized. This is how Pandas/Numpy works. Put it differently, there is no way to significantly speed the process (in sequential) without modifying `fn1`. Not all functions can be vectorized (eg. working on lists of variable sizes). Other modules can sometime help in such case, but this is impossible to tell without the code of `fn1`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I understand. That's why I gave up trying to vectorize the function and instead used the df. apply(lambda..) function BUT used joblib over it to parallelize the calls to fn1. I don't know how exactly it worked inside, but this definitely sped up the performance by ~12 times as compared to just iteratively calling fn1 via df. apply(lambda..). And this speed improvement was noticeable only for larger df sizes which was anyway my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try parallelizing the computation using the multiprocessing library.

This is how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fn1(row, a, b):
    # Implement your function here. I used a + b for simplicity
    result = a + b
    return result

def fn1_wrapper(args):
    row, a, b = args
    return fn1(row, a, b)

# I cannot find your DF sample you mentioned in your question, so I created a fake one to test it
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 2689))
a = 0.5
b = 0.25

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:  # Adjust the 'processes' parameter based on your CPU cores
    results = pool.map(fn1_wrapper, [(row, a, b) for _, row in df.iterrows()])

# Assigning the results to a new column in the DataFrame
df['final'] = results
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I have run the code & I have two follow-up questions on this. First, isn't itertools the slowest option when iterating through any df rows? Can't we replace that part with anything else but still doing the multiprocessing. Second, I do not have access parallel computing resource allocation on the remote computing resources I use. So is this the reason why the code is just stuck when I run it even for 1*2413 sized df? Or is it due to the itertools function?

Comment: Lack of access to parallel computing is an issue of course. I guess you mean `iterrows` and not `itertools`. It's not easy to answer without knowing the exact `fn1` function. Everything might be a guess

Comment: Oh yes, I meant iterrows. Sorry my bad!  fn1 contains a loop supposed to operate on a row of a df. This loop inside this fn1 not related to df looping but rather some other operation. This operation involves extracting values like [a:b] & that's why I convert the incoming df input to list or numpy so that I can do this slicing operation inside my fn1 loop. I cannot improve this loop and it has to be there. So I wanted this loop operation to be performed on each df row (i.e. 100 rows or more) in an efficient manner by hoping for a solution (vectorized?) that can apply this fn1 on the whole df.

Comment: In response to your comment about fn1 unavailability, I have posted a new question that details this and my above response. Can you please look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802507/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-use-my-function-on-a-dataframe

Comment: I accept your answer since it gave me the idea of parallelizing the calls to fn1. However, I did not use iterrows as it made it slow and instead used the df. apply(lambda..) function BUT used joblib over it to parallelize the calls to fn1. I don't know how exactly it worked inside, but this definitely sped up the performance by ~12 times as compared to just iteratively calling fn1 via df. apply(lambda..). And this speed improvement was noticeable only for larger df sizes which was any way my need.

Answer (score 0):

Looping at Python level over a Pandas DataFrame is slow. Full stop. The recommended approaches are to only use pandas or numpy functions, because they are written in C language under the hood and are much faster when processing numeric values.

If this is not an option, the alternative solution is to use Cython or Numba to convert the function containing the for loop into a C native function that could then be used a C speed. Not as straightforward as one could hope, but can be very effective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too read of these other solutions but didn't use them since I was short of time and didn't want to switch to something new. But finally, I used the df. apply(lambda..) function BUT used joblib over it to parallelize the calls to fn1. I don't know how exactly it worked inside, but this definitely sped up the performance by ~12 times as compared to just iteratively calling fn1 via df. apply(lambda..). And this speed improvement was noticeable only for larger df sizes which was anyway my need.