# How to efficiently call my function on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, vectorization

I have a data frame `df` of size 100 (or more eventually) rows and 2418 columns. For each row of this `df` I want to apply a function `fn1` that contains a loop. I cannot avoid this loop. So I want to time efficiently apply this fn1 to the whole df. A simplified code is given below.

```
def fn1(row,a,b):
   i=list(row)  #only because I do slicing operation later

   x= i[0:a]+ something   #in my case I have a loop here that does some operation but has slicing too
   y=i[b:end]+ something
 
   result= some_evaluatefn(x,y)   
   return result
```

I call this fn1 as below

```
df['f']= df.apply(lambda row: fn1(row,a,b), axis=1, raw=True)
```

Another approach I tried was (but gave an error'numpy.float64' object is not iterable)

```
vectfunc=np.vectorize(fn1)       
df['f'] = vectfunc(df[df.columns[0:]],a, b)  
#or
df['f'] = vectfunc(df,a, b)
```

Can anyone please suggest a **time-efficient way** to do this `fn1()` over all rows of `df`? **Is it entirely dependent on what is inside `fn1`, or is there still scope to call `fn1` in a way that the time is reduced such that the operation is performed on all rows?**

I also tried removing the fn1() and instead putting the content directly in place of function call
in which the `i` was directly replaced by `df`. I.e.

```
i=df.to_numpy()  #instead of i=list(row) inside fn1
#or
i=df.values.tolist()
```

but these gave error in my subsequent code as these are not operating on a particular row.

The other methods I tried are given in this question [Problem with looping over pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796531/problem-with-looping-over-pandas-dataframe/75799690?noredirect=1#comment133713539_75799690)

Comment: you may want to switch to numpy (using `df.values`), compute there what you need, preferably using vectorized functions / numba, eventually saving all results in the dataframe using single operation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried something similar to what you said. But finally, I used the df. apply(lambda..) function BUT used joblib over it to parallelize the calls to fn1. I don't know how exactly it worked inside, but this definitely sped up the performance by ~12 times as compared to just iteratively calling fn1 via df. apply(lambda..). And this speed improvement was noticeable only for larger df sizes which was anyway my need.